# JQ transformation from a JSON array to simple JSON based on array elements value matching else null string

Tags: jq

I'm trying to transform below JSON using JQ. Wanted to transform it to a simple JSON which has city if relation's primary is true and relation address type is project. Wanted to populate it as empty string as "" in case source is not having a relation address type of project.

```
{
    "miscellenous" : "apple",
    "relations" : [ 
        {
            "primary": false,
            "rel" : 123,
            "address" : [
                {
                    "type" : "project",
                    "city" : "xyz"
                },
                {
                    "type" : "mailing",
                    "city" : "abc"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "primary": true,
            "rel" : 456,
            "address" : [
                {
                    "type" : "project",
                    "city" : "xyz"
                },
                {
                    "type" : "mailing",
                    "city" : "abc"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It's working if values are matching that is primary is true and address type is "project" available in source JSON then transformation is working fine with either of the below JQ logic. But it's not giving expected response if address type "project" is not available and it's giving blank JSON.

Using select

```
{
 "miscellenous" : .miscellenous,
 "city" :  .relations[] | select(.primary == true) | .address[] | select(.type == "project") | .city
}
```

Using if else

```
{
 "miscellenous" : .miscellenous,
 "city" :  .relations[] | (if .primary == true then .address[] | (if .type == "project" then .city else empty end) else empty end)
}
```

Expected output if address type "project" is available in source JSON - This is working as expected

```
{
  "miscellenous": "apple",
  "city": "xyz"
}
```

Expected output if address type "project" is not available in source JSON -  This is not working as expected as it's blanking out whole JSON if "project" type address is not available in source.

```
{
      "miscellenous": "apple",
      "city": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [alternative operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Alternativeoperator%3A%2F%2F) `//` to provide a default value:

```bash
{
  miscellenous,
  "city": (
    (.relations[] | select(.primary) | .address[] | select(.type == "project") | .city) // ""
  )
}
```

Note: Instead of `{"miscellenous" : .miscellenous}` you can just write `{miscellenous}`, and instead of `select(.primary == true)` you can just write `select(.primary)`.